# How to read the n last lines of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have to read the 4 last line of a file.

I tried the following:

```
top_tb_comp_file = open('../../ver/sim/top_tb_compile.tcl', 'r+')
top_tb_comp_end = top_tb_comp_file.readlines()[:-4]
top_tb_comp_file.close()
```

Didn't work (I get the first line of the file in `top_tb_comp_end`).

Answer (score 2):

Your indexing is wrong. With the `[:-4]`, you are asking for the exact opposite of what you actually want.

Try the following:

```
top_tb_comp_file = open('../../ver/sim/top_tb_compile.tcl', 'r+')
top_tb_comp_end = top_tb_comp_file.readlines()[-4:]
# you noticed that the '-4' is now before the ':'
top_tb_comp_file.close()
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Noctis, I have made some benchmarking around the question. About the speed and memory usage of the [`collection.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) option and [`file.readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) one.

The `collection` option suggested by @Noctis seems to be better in term of memory usage **AND** speed: in my result I observed a little peak in the memory usage at the critical line `file.readlines()[-4:]` which did not happened at the line `collections.deque(file, 4)`. Moreover, I repeated the speed test with the file reading phase and the `collections` option seems also faster in this case.

I have experienced some issues displaying the ouput of this code with the SO rendering but if you install the packages [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) and [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) you should be able to see by yourself (with large sized file).

```
import sys
import collections
import time

from memory_profiler import profile


@profile
def coll_func(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        lines = collections.deque(file, 4)
    return 0


@profile
def indexing_func(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()[-4:]
    return 0


@profile
def witness_func(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        pass
    return 0


def square_star(s_toprint, ext="-"):
    def surround(s, ext="+"):
        return ext + s + ext

    hbar = "-" * (len(s_toprint) + 1)
    return (surround(hbar) + "\n"
            + surround(s_toprint, ext='|') + "\n"
            + surround(hbar))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s_fname = sys.argv[1]
    s_func = sys.argv[2]

    d_func = {
        "1": coll_func,
        "2": indexing_func,
        "3": witness_func
    }

    func = d_func[s_func]

    start = time.time()
    func(s_fname)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start

    s_toprint = square_star("Elapsed time:\t{}".format(elapsed_time))

    print(s_toprint)
```

**Just type the following:**

```
python3 -m memory_profiler profile.py "my_file.txt" n
```

n being 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: I ran this on an ~1.2G file with python 3.10.6. Execution time for `deque` was about 50% faster (1.0s vs 1.5s) and memory usage was less with `deque` using 0.5MiB and `readlines` using 30MiB

Answer (score 1):

The following example opens a file named `names.txt` and prints the last 4 lines in the file. Applied to your example, you only need to take away the pattern given on lines 2, 5, and 7. The rest is simple.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections


def main():
    with open('names.txt') as file:
        lines = collections.deque(file, 4)
    print(*lines, sep='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick but I'm not sure it is really worth it. A better indexing seem to me more simple and is actually faster:

`In [6]: import collections

In [7]: liste = list(range(1000000))

In [8]: %timeit lines = collections.deque(liste, 4)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.95 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit lines = liste[-4:]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 115 ns per loop`

Comment: What happens if you run a memory profile on the two methods?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Could you do it yourself and share your results, please?

Comment: That makes two of us who lack the knowledge for such a task. I can make some approximations in Windows, but most people would probably be more interested is seeing the results from Linux.

Comment: I'm just leaving my work place. I'll do it later and share it as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks! You may want to test both approaches with large files as well. Memory usage would be significantly different with a 1 GB text file with a million lines of text.